# iPhone tab bar with custom buttons and scrollview

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uibutton, tabbar

I'm trying to get a tab bar effect not unlike [Russell Quinn's Creative Review app](http://www.russellquinn.com/blog/2010/04/22/creative-review-annual-2010-iphone-app/). The tab bar swipes across, which I have figured out, but the tab bar style itself is unlike anything I've seen on the iPhone (though it looks so simple!).

It has square buttons with a space between, and each button has a select/active/inactive state. I'm having a hard time seeing how this can be a tab bar, but i don't know any other way. Can someone explain this?

**EDIT:**

thanks to yukla for the guidance, I got it working using `uibutton`. It was pretty basic and fairly embarrassing that I couldn't think this up... in my `rootviewcontroller.m`, I tossed this in after i synthesized `homeBtn`.

```
- (UIButton *) homeBtn {
    homeBtn = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
    homeBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 45);
    [homeBtn setTitle:@"Home" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [homeBtn setTitle:@"Home" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [homeBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [homeBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"disabled.png"] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    [homeBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [homeBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"highlighted.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [homeBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"highlighted+selected.png"] forState:(UIControlStateHighlighted | UIControlStateSelected)];
    [homeBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(switchPages:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return homeBtn;
}
```

Just subclass it from UISwipeView and you're all set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about a scroll view with buttons instead of a tab bar?? you can have different image/background for normal/selected/disabled state. but then you'll have to write your own code for loading the different views.

Comment: thanks mate. i actually got the answer from the source (russel quinn, creative review app). he said what he did was make each button just a UIView. the backgroundColor property is set in response to the regular touchesBegan, touchesEnded, etc. methods. then just create a bunch of those and put them inside a UIScrollView.

agreed though, i'll definitely need to write my own code to load different views, but that's not terribly difficult. thanks for the quick response!